# Parsing Android String to JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a JSONString that came back successfully and I want to convert it into a JSONArray where I can parse the bits. The string came back successfully but when I try to log the "title" within each movie's object inside the "results" array, it's not coming up.

```
public List<MovieItem> fetchItems() {

List<MovieItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    String url = Uri.parse("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular")
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)

            .build().toString();


    String jsonString = getUrlString(url);
    Log.i(TAG, "Received JSON: " + jsonString);


    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray photoJsonArray = jsonBody.getJSONArray("results");


    for(int i = 0; i < photoJsonArray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject jsonPart = photoJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("title"));
    }


} catch (IOException ioe) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch items", ioe);
} catch (JSONException je) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse", je);
}
return items;
}
```

-

```
02-03 13:34:43.236 4728-4746/? I/MovieFetchr: Received JSON: {
"page":1,
"results":[
    {
        "poster_path":"\/oXUWEc5i3wYyFnL1Ycu8ppxxPvs.jpg",
        "adult":false,
        "overview":"In the 1820s, a frontiersman, Hugh Glass, sets out on a path of vengeance against those who left him for dead after a bear mauling.",
        "release_date":"2015-12-25",
        "genre_ids":[37,18,12,53],
        "id":281957,
        "original_title":"The Revenant",
        "original_language":"en",
        "title":"The Revenant",
        "backdrop_path":"\/uETWtwsE1QjfoFqRQqFLnSjppPA.jpg",
        "popularity":42.096309,
        "vote_count":1079,
        "video":false,
        "vote_average":7.36
    },
    {
        "poster_path":"\/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg",
        "adult":false,
        "overview":"An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos. And Furiosa, a woman of action and a woman who believes her path to survival may be achieved if she can make it across the desert back to her childhood homeland.",
        "release_date":"2015-05-13",
        "genre_ids":[878,53,28,12],
        "id":76341,
        "original_title":"Mad Max: Fury Road",
        "original_language":"en",
        "title":"Mad Max: Fury Road",
        "backdrop_path":"\/tbhdm8UJAb4ViCTsulYFL3lxMCd.jpg",
        "popularity":32.157869,
        "vote_count":3566,
        "video":false,
        "vote_average":7.5
    },
```

Comment: Are you getting any error here?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The Genymotion emulator loads up fine. The JSON string comes back fine as shown. It's just that it's not logging the individual title when I convert the JSONstring into a jsonArray. Thanks.

Comment: Seems all good. Did you try to debug?

Comment: I hope you have not filtered out locat output based on any criteria.

Comment: Thanks  Rohit5k2. Silly me. The filter from a previous search was in there. All solved. Junior mistake. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is really funny..... :D

Comment: Also you should mark the answer by @jaskarnsingh as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("title"));
```

to

```
Log.i(TAG, "Title: " + jsonPart.getString("title"));
```

and comment out the above log statement so it can be read easily